# Reading deeply nested xml with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I promise I've seen different examples in stackoverflow of reading XML's but none of them work for me. I'm reading an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ASSETS ASOF_DATE="10/22/2021" CREATE_DATE="10/22/2021" RECORDS="140">
    <ASSET><EQUITY_EQUITY>
        <ACCRUAL_DT>12/1/2009</ACCRUAL_DT>
        <ASSET_BENCHMARK>BRT6U6V13</ASSET_BENCHMARK>
        <CALC_TYPE>0</CALC_TYPE>
        <CD_INSTMT_TYPE>UNKNOWN</CD_INSTMT_TYPE>
        <CHANGE_DT>10/22/2021 0:14:46.800</CHANGE_DT>
        <COMPOUND_FLAG>0</COMPOUND_FLAG>
        <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
        <CURRENCY>USD</CURRENCY>
        <CUSIP>464286400</CUSIP>
        <CUSIP2_set SIZE="6">
            <CUSIP2_record>
                <CODE>A</CODE>
                <IDENTIFIER>464286400</IDENTIFIER>
            </CUSIP2_record>
            <CUSIP2_record>
                <CODE>C</CODE>
                <IDENTIFIER>2726014</IDENTIFIER>
            </CUSIP2_record>
            <CUSIP2_record>
                <CODE>I</CODE>
                <IDENTIFIER>US4642864007</IDENTIFIER>
            </CUSIP2_record>
            <CUSIP2_record>
                <CODE>R</CODE>
                <IDENTIFIER>EWZ.P</IDENTIFIER>
            </CUSIP2_record>
            <CUSIP2_record>
                <CODE>g</CODE>
                <IDENTIFIER>1I_EWZ_*</IDENTIFIER>
            </CUSIP2_record>
            <CUSIP2_record>
                <CODE>2</CODE>
                <IDENTIFIER>EWZ US</IDENTIFIER>
            </CUSIP2_record>
        </CUSIP2_set>
        <CUSIP_ALIAS_set SIZE="2">
            <CUSIP_ALIAS_record>
                <CODE>42</CODE>
                <IDENTIFIER>464286400</IDENTIFIER>
                <PURPOSE>CUSIP</PURPOSE>
            </CUSIP_ALIAS_record>
            <CUSIP_ALIAS_record>
                <CODE>70</CODE>
                <IDENTIFIER>US4642864007</IDENTIFIER>
                <PURPOSE>ISIN</PURPOSE>
            </CUSIP_ALIAS_record>
        </CUSIP_ALIAS_set>
        <CUSIP_TYPE>CUSIP</CUSIP_TYPE>
        <DESC_INSTMT>ISHARES MSCI BRAZIL ETF</DESC_INSTMT>
        <DESC_INSTMT2>ETF-E</DESC_INSTMT2>
        <DR_TYPE>N</DR_TYPE>
        <EXCHANGE>NYSEARC</EXCHANGE>
        <FLAG_144A>N</FLAG_144A>
        <FLAG_PERFORMING>Y</FLAG_PERFORMING>
        <ISSUER_ID>E96351</ISSUER_ID>
        <ISSUE_DT>12/1/2009</ISSUE_DT>
        <LIQUIDITY>L</LIQUIDITY>
        <MARKET>US</MARKET>
        <MARKET_MIC>ARCX</MARKET_MIC>
        <MIN_LOT_SIZE>1</MIN_LOT_SIZE>
        <MIN_TRD_SIZE>1</MIN_TRD_SIZE>
        <MODIFIED_BY>sm_timestamp</MODIFIED_BY>
        <MTN>N</MTN>
        <NTL_FLAG>N</NTL_FLAG>
        <PMT_FREQ_TYPE>0</PMT_FREQ_TYPE>
        <PRICE_AS_PCT>N</PRICE_AS_PCT>
        <PRICING>100ths</PRICING>
        <REVIEWED_BY>f2socamp</REVIEWED_BY>
        <SECTOR_set SIZE="2">
            <SECTOR_record>
                <CODE>295</CODE>
                <LEVEL>16</LEVEL>
                <TYPE>COVERAGE</TYPE>
            </SECTOR_record>
            <SECTOR_record>
                <CODE>NARC</CODE>
                <LEVEL>1</LEVEL>
                <TYPE>REUT_SEGM</TYPE>
            </SECTOR_record>
        </SECTOR_set>
        <SEC_TYPE>EQUITY_EQUITY</SEC_TYPE>
        <SM_SEC_GROUP>EQUITY</SM_SEC_GROUP>
        <SM_SEC_TYPE>EQUITY</SM_SEC_TYPE>
        <TICKER>EWZ</TICKER>
        <WI_FLAG>N</WI_FLAG>
    </EQUITY_EQUITY></ASSET>
    </ASSETS>
```

The standard

```
df = pd.read_xml(file, xpath='.//ASSET')
```

Gives me a pretty decent dataframe, but I lose the info I want, which is this:

```
<CUSIP2_record>
                <CODE>g</CODE>
                <IDENTIFIER>1I_EWZ_*</IDENTIFIER>
```

(This is nested inside the `<CUSIP2_set SIZE="6">` tag.

The dataframe I get reads the column `CUSIP2_set` as just `Nan`, but in theory that variable should be a list because there are many variables inside `CUSIP2_set`, as can be seen in the example file.

The ET library is also not working. If I do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
data = 'blabla.xml'
tree = ET.parse(data)
root = tree.getroot()

for cusip in root.iter('CUSIP'): 
  print(cusip.attrib)
```

I get empty dictionaries.

I would like to have a dataframe like this (I'm using the whole file, if you only use this example you will only have one row):

[image]

Except that the column CUSIP2_set must not be empty. (It is full of Np.Nan's with my code).

What would work for me is that the CUSIP2_set column contains the relevante code from that subfield ( in the example file, this record is: `<CUSIP2_record> <CODE>g</CODE> <IDENTIFIER>1I_EWZ_*</IDENTIFIER>`;

I only need the `1I_EWZ_*`  part).

This column can also contain a list with all the variable inside CUSIP2_set (all the subfields).

Comment: Are you using pandas because you want to use the XML with data science or something like that? Or are you just trying to parse XML in Python in any way possible?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the expected dataframe from the XML example? XML is a complex format and not every layout is compatible with `pd.read_xml`.

Comment: @user17242583 I am just trying to parse it in any way possible.

Comment: @CodeDifferent Yes! You're Right. Thanks for pointing this out. Let me edit the question now.

Comment: This was 2+ years ago, I honestly can't remember how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `xmltodict` and `flatten_json`

set your xml to xmltoparse (just any variable name as a string)

```
import xmltodict
from flatten_json import flatten
#this will create a json object
data = json.loads(json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(xmltoparse)))

# this will put all items into a single row
dic_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in [data])
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
```

Ouput

```
  ASSETS.@ASOF_DATE ASSETS.@CREATE_DATE ASSETS.@RECORDS  ... ASSETS.ASSET.EQUITY_EQUITY.SM_SEC_TYPE ASSETS.ASSET.EQUITY_EQUITY.TICKER ASSETS.ASSET.EQUITY_EQUITY.WI_FLAG
0        10/22/2021          10/22/2021             140  ...                                 EQUITY                               EWZ                                  N

[1 rows x 65 columns]
```

Different view

```
In [67]: df.iloc[0]
Out[67]:
ASSETS.@ASOF_DATE                                10/22/2021
ASSETS.@CREATE_DATE                              10/22/2021
ASSETS.@RECORDS                                         140
ASSETS.ASSET.EQUITY_EQUITY.ACCRUAL_DT             12/1/2009
ASSETS.ASSET.EQUITY_EQUITY.ASSET_BENCHMARK        BRT6U6V13
                                                  ...
ASSETS.ASSET.EQUITY_EQUITY.SEC_TYPE           EQUITY_EQUITY
ASSETS.ASSET.EQUITY_EQUITY.SM_SEC_GROUP              EQUITY
ASSETS.ASSET.EQUITY_EQUITY.SM_SEC_TYPE               EQUITY
ASSETS.ASSET.EQUITY_EQUITY.TICKER                       EWZ
ASSETS.ASSET.EQUITY_EQUITY.WI_FLAG                        N
Name: 0, Length: 65, dtype: object
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why I get this error: 


```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xmltodict.py", line 327, in parse
    parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0```?

Comment: No, not really. It’s saying xml isn’t well formed. Are you passing it as a string? Using triple single quotes around it? That’s how I got your ample to work. Otherwise your example may not be fully representative of your actual xml.